# Please Help. Converting 24 bit image to 8 bit

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can convert an 24 bit jpeg image to 8 bit jpeg in vb.net? help please.i keep getting a 24 bit image when i save.

Comment: This is off topic, and I'm not voting to migrate it as the quality is so bad it won't be accepted else where. Use a search engine.  -1 However, this does what you want http://bfy.tw/6l08

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/ which will work with .NET:

> FreeImage is an Open Source library project for developers who would like to support popular graphics image formats like PNG, BMP, JPEG, TIFF and others as needed by today's multimedia applications. FreeImage is easy to use, fast, multithreading safe, compatible with all 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Windows, and cross-platform (works both with Linux and Mac OS X).

Also see http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/369150-how-to-convert-a-24-bit-rgb-bmp-to-8-bit-grayscale/